# Meteor's Tutorial Step 11

Tags: meteor

For some reason I can't get the last part of Step 11 of the Meteor tutorial to work.   The url for the step is here:  https://www.meteor.com/try/11

The part that's not working for me is the very last step which reads "In order to finish up our private task feature, we need to add checks to our deleteTask and setChecked methods to make sure only the task owner can delete or check off a private task:"

When I add the code to the deleteTask and setChecked methods, users in other browsers can still remove and check/uncheck a different user's tasks.

This is what my deleteTask and setChecked functions look like after making the modifications.   Perhaps I did it all wrong?

```
deleteTask: function (taskId) {
    var task = Tasks.findOne(taskId);
    if (task.private && task.owner !== Meteor.userId()) {
      // If the task is private, make sure only the owner can delete it
      throw new Meteor.Error("not-authorized");
    }  
    Tasks.remove(taskId);
},
setChecked: function (taskId, setChecked) {
    var task = Tasks.findOne(taskId);
    if (task.private && task.owner !== Meteor.userId()) {
       // If the task is private, make sure only the owner can check it off
       throw new Meteor.Error("not-authorized");
    }
    Tasks.update(taskId, { $set: { checked: setChecked} });
 },
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Hmm, I forgot about the code examples at the bottom of each tutorial step.   When I open those, those methods look the same as mine.  Stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you implemented in step 11 prevents other users from checking/unchecking other users' **private tasks**.

From your code:

```
// If the task is **private**, make sure only the owner can delete it
```

Users can still check/uncheck different users' tasks if they are **public**.

Comment: Bingo!  Now I get it.  :)  I wish their tutorial didn't make it only private --  that way we could see that step work (private ones get removed from non-owners).   Obviously now that you explained it I can modify it to remove the private requirement, but I think it would be more educational if it were the way I was anticipating it.

Comment: :). If you didn't do step 11 then people would be able to use the javascript console and remove other peoples private todos. 

I think their aim is to show you how to give a user the right view and edit their own private data. 

With a little hacking around I'm sure you could turn the 'private task' into a 'locked task'. And that would have the behaviour you'd like to see. :)

Comment: Well I wouldn't change anything about step 11, except make it where the checkboxes and delete aren't useable unless you own them.   That's the more natural expectation when you are dealing with security.   The way it is, when someone makes it "private" it disappears entirely on the other person's screen -- so there is no way to test the functionality of what they are trying to demonstrate (which is security).

Answer (score 0):

As alfreema says, how to prevent other users from deleting the public tasks.

```
deleteTask: function (taskId) {
    // Inside the deleteTask method
    var task = Tasks.findOne(taskId);
    if (task.public && task.owner !== Meteor.userId()) {
        // If the task is public, make sure only the owner can delete it
        throw new Meteor.Error("not-authorized");
    }
    Tasks.remove(taskId);
},

setChecked: function (taskId, setChecked) {
    var task = Tasks.findOne(taskId);
    if (task.public && task.owner !== Meteor.userId()) {
        // If the task is public, make sure only the owner can check it off
        throw new Meteor.Error("not-authorized");
    }
    Tasks.update(taskId, { $set: { checked: setChecked} });
}
```

Though if we update the code as above, replacing task.private with      task.public, Whereas it still allows to delete the tasks.